# Access Login Control from Different Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, forms-authentication

I have a website in C# where users are authenticated to a SQL database via  login control. Everything is working fine currently as I'm using the web.config to to direct to the Login.aspx page if the user isn't logged in. What I would like to do though is access the login controls from another page but additionally pass another parameter.

So for example...

The web.config has the following:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="20"></forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

The Login.aspx page looks like the following

```
protected void LoginControl_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    bool authenticated = this.ValidateCredentials(LoginControl.UserName, LoginControl.Password);

    if (authenticated)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(LoginControl.UserName, LoginControl.RememberMeSet);
    }
}

private bool IsAlphaNumeric(string text)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(text, "^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$");
}

private bool ValidateCredentials(string userName, string password)
{
    bool returnValue = false;

    if (this.IsAlphaNumeric(userName) && userName.Length <= 25 && password.Length <= 50)
    {
        string sqlConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(sqlConn))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = ("ValidateUser");
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LoginName", userName.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LoginPass", HashData.HashString(password.Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Type", "Read");
                cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

                sqlConnection1.Open();

                if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() == null)
                {
                    returnValue = false;
                }

                else
                {
                    returnValue = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

}

Now what I would like to do is utilize the same login control across other pages so that I can see if the same user is logged in but pass a different "Type" parameter such as "Edit".

So the way I would like it to work is this... The users accesses the site and is redirected to the Login.aspx page. The login control runs my stored procedure verifying they are "Read" type and redirects them to the Default.aspx. From here a user can click an Edit button. Once they do, the same login control would check if they have "Edit" rights by running the same stored procedure but instead passing that as the "Type" parameter. At this point if the results are false the user would be prompted to login if their current rights don't allow it, or the page would just load if the current user has those rights.  Is there a way to do what I"m looking for or would I need to just user either multiple login controls or different folder structure and do this all with web.config?

Comment: are you familiar with `Session` variables.. could you not hold the valid logged in user in a session variable and in the page_load check if the user is valid and proceed with your edit logic / tracking from there.. you could have 2 `Session` variables one for login and another for edit and is Valid login

Comment: @MethodMan If I used session variables, wouldn't I need to keep the password in one as well so I could re-run the query? That was my concern with using them. As far as the "Edit" in a session variable, there could be a dozen different possible "Types" and the user could have any number of them represented as a bit type in the database so I don't believe I can keep that in a variable just rerun a query with the type on a given page. If I'm mistaken, please clarify.

Comment: no..you don't expose passwords.. if you validate that the user name and password from a user after logging in the first time.. then I ask you logically would that make sense to check / store their password in a Session...? `The answer is NO...!` sounds like you need to do a bit more reading up / research on authentication and validation

Comment: @MethodMan that was exactly what I was saying. That I would not want to store the password but was asking how that could be done short of that.

Comment: how are you checking the user / password.. are the users stored in a database or AD ..? or both.. you are hashing the password.. so you need to return something if the user and password are in the database.. I don't understand where you are getting confused..

Comment: @MethodMan as my original posts states, the users are stored in a SQL database. I can't retain the "Type" of edit and carry that as a session variable as I would have at this point a dozen and could become more. This seems like not an effective way to assign that many session variables. So my logic is that I would need to check if the user had the correct access on each page. I'm not seeing how I can pass existing authenticated user and rerun the query with the different "type" each time. Maybe I'm just not following your logic here, if so please clarify.

Comment: you could alter your query or you could create a table that has users defined like user rights roles etc.. there are other options to doing this as well within .net framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved...

What I ended up doing was to let the login control authorize a user with the lowest level rights. When a user attempts to access a page that requires higher rights, I'm first checking if

```
 if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
```

If true, then I run a new query that checks if User.Identity.Name is of the correct "Type".

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a Master page and put the Login Control in the Master page.  Have each page that you want to be able to authenticate inherit from the Master page, which would give it access to the Login Control.

Comment: and every page in his application assuming it's not just a single page ..prior to rendering.. would hit the `MasterPages  Page_Load` event.. thus still needing a way to track the valid login.. there are many ways to skin this cat..